# CStarRating allways shows a radio button in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to use the `CStarRating` widget in yii, but i am facing a weird problem, instead of showing the stars it shows radio buttons.
Here is my code:

```
$this->widget('CStarRating',array(
            'name'=>'rating_4',
            'value'=>'3',
            'minRating'=>1,
            'maxRating'=>5,
            'titles'=>array(
                '1'=>'Normal',
                '2'=>'Average',
                '3'=>'OK',
                '4'=>'Good',
                '5'=>'Excellent'
                ),
                 ));
```

Do i need to have anything else in order to use this widget. Thanks in advance

Comment: CStarRating shows radio buttons only if there is a javascript error, meaning that jqueryui did not load, check your console/firebug for javascript errors

Comment: @Manquer it say's 
`TypeError: jQuery(...).rating is not a function
jQuery('#rating_4 > input').rating();`
how do i resolve it? please help

Comment: Most likely case for error is that it has nothing to do with CStarRating, any javascript error on the page will cause problems with rest of the scripts on the page, since CStarRating is generated by yii it unlikely to be the cause of the error, check all the js in that page for syntax errors first,

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the CStarRating widget under import in your config properly? 
Probably the error is that the widget is not imported and then falls back graciously to standard html radio buttons which is the stylized building block for this component.

For example, besides the default paths i'm including mobiledetect from the extensions folder like this (excerpt from my config):

```
// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.controllers.*',

    // Below are extensions
    // Mobile Detect (http://mobiledetect.net/)
    'application.extensions.mobiledetect.*',
```

In case your widget is imported properly: in your Chrome / Firefox there is also a developer panel usually accessed by pressing F12, if you go to the console you should be able to see any JS errors that prevents your widget from being rendered properly.

Hope this helps!